# Swift3 Unable to link referencing outlet

Tags: uiview, reference, swift3

I'm defining a Custom UIView based on a XIB. Therefor I have copied CustomXIBSwift-master from Github. That works very well. I adapted it briefly for my purposes.

The label (lblTitle) is linked as a referencing outlet to the File's Owner
[image]

Now I also want to make a referencing outlet for the second sublabel to File's Owner. However I'm not able to linke this using the dot-line method nor by including the IBOutlet manually.

[image]

Based on the CustomXIBSwift-master the XIB is of type UIView. When I specify a custom class (instead of UIView) it crashes.

Part of the SWIFT code:

```
func loadViewFromNib() {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "SlidingAlertView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(view);
}
```

How can I make a referencing outlet from this View to the Swift file?

Comment: You need to implement the `IBOutlet` in the `SimpleCustomView` class.

Comment: I have IBOutlets defined, but I'm not able to connect them with the UILabels in de XIB

Comment: The class of the view must be set to the name of the subclass (like in the first screenshot).

Comment: I don't understand. Obviously the outlet appears in the first screenshot. So check all classes (especially File's Owner).

Comment: That is correct. The first screenshot is from the code from Github. There a ReferencingOutlet exists. I want to add a new UILabel, but I'm not able to make a ReferencingOutlet for this second UILabel.

Comment: Create the outlet in the same class as the existing outlet. However If no outlet appears at all then the class is not set to the subclass.

Comment: I have tried that earlier. When you do that in the Connection Inspector the Referencing Outlet is listed as "SlidingAlertView". That crashes on runtime. It has to be "File's Owner", see the 1st image in the post.

Comment: Once again, compare **all** settings in the Identity Inspector (⌥⌘3) of **all** objects with the GitHub class.

Comment: See the answer below. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make a connection between the UILabels and the File's Owner. It appeared that also for the File's Owner thee Custom Class can be specified.

[image]